# wikipedia servers gzip content

Tags: php, curl, wikimedia

does wikimedia api supports gzip encoding. I'm using curl to get the content. I have used the accept gzip encoding. But it does not seem to work..

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

Comment: Can you post a [reproducible complete test case](http://sscce.org/) including the specific URL you're requesting? How have you determined that gzip is not used?

Comment: How can you see gzip is not used?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' to get request headers? I tried it with this sample:

http://pastebin.com/AmndVB3e

and it sent it gzipped content.

Answer (score 0):

Try (let me know if it works, I can't tell myself from the rest of your Curl options)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "deflate, gzip, identity");
```

Comment: Why should this work? Every web server in existence supports identity, and why should the addition of new transfer encodings have any effect in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your literal question: yes, it does.

One way to test this is to install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and visit [a MediaWiki API URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) with the "Net" tab active.  The response headers you'll see should look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 May 2012 23:05:37 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: private
MediaWiki-API-Error: help
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 37421
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cache: MISS from sq59.wikimedia.org, MISS from amssq35.esams.wikimedia.org, MISS from amssq44.esams.wikimedia.org
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq59.wikimedia.org:3128, MISS from amssq35.esams.wikimedia.org:3128, MISS from amssq44.esams.wikimedia.org:80
Connection: keep-alive
```

(And no, it's not just because of Wikipedia's front end proxies, either; I just tried the same on my own wiki, which is not behind a proxy, and got the same `Content-Encoding` header.)